# Change colour of axis labels in base R

Tags: r

I would like to change the colour of the axis labels in Base R. Worked out how to change the axis line colour but there seems to be no switch in the axis to change the label colour.
The minimal example below ... how do I make all the numeric labels along each axis grey (4.5 to 8.0 horizontal axis and 1 to 7 vertical axis) and the axis labels (iris$Sepal.Length and iris$Petal.Length)?

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Petal.Length, 
bty = "n", axes = FALSE)
axis(1, col = "grey")
axis(2, col = "grey", las = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the axis labels by using the col.axis parameter in the par() function like such:

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length, bty = "n", axes = FALSE)

# Set the axis line color
axis(1, col = "grey")
axis(2, col = "grey", las = 1)

# Set the axis label color
par(col.axis = "grey")
```

Comment: Yes ... I know that trick but prefer to leave the par values alone if at all possible ... thanks anyway for replying

Comment: So the thing I was looking for was col.axis =  "grey"  which changes the colors of the axis labels